# How can i use require.context in my webpack project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, require

I'm doing a website. I have a source "src" with pug, scss, js, jpeg, png and etc in different directories. And I have a "build" directory, where webpack compile files from "src".
I want to export all media files (like jpeg) to "build".

The entry file for webpack is `/src/index.js`

For this i'm trying to use `require.context()`
https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext

I type in "/src/index.js" `require.context('Src/', true, /\.(png|svg|jpg|mp3)$/);`. But get the error:

> "error 'require' is not defined".

BUT I can use `window.Vue = require('vue')` for example, and its working. I don't understand what I should do to make this happen.